# IDX10214: Audience validation failed. ADFS .Net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ssl, adfs, wif

I'm validating against my ADFS server and am getting the following error message.

`"IDX10214: Audience validation failed. Audiences Did not match:  validationParameters.ValidAudience"`

This [link](http://brianvanderplaats.com/2017/01/18/ADFS-Authentication-Using-Visual-Studio-Wizard/) shows my code--its a very simple proof-of-concept for authenticating within the visual studio IDE.  It takes only a few minutes to create the project--this should be simple.

Comment: I closed and reopened Visual Studio 2015 and got a different error.  Now when debugging in Firefox I get SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG when debugging in Chrome I get  ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Answer (score 0):

OK, I was implementing this [code](http://brianvanderplaats.com/2017/01/18/ADFS-Authentication-Using-Visual-Studio-Wizard/) when I got the above issue and the root cause was the web.api checkbox wasn't clicked when I created the .net 4.5 project

[image: click web api checkbox]

[image: .net 4.5]

Also make sure the application property url matches matches the adfs registered url.  Also, visual studio requires the port to be in the range 44300 to (I think) 47000?

[image: adfs url on premise]
[image: web properties url]